# argoCD ApplicationSet - repository not accessible

Tags: github-actions, argocd

I am getting subjected error while deploying helm using argoCD applicationSet with gitHubActions. Below is yaml. repoURL is correct.

Error :

InvalidSpecError: repository not accessible: repo client error while testing repository: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error testing repository connectivity: repository "" cannot be initialized: repo URL is invalid"

Interesting thing is its working with argoCD application.yaml with same config.

Can someone please suggest the issue?

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
  - list:
      elements:
      - prefix: app1
        url: test1
      - prefix: app2
        url: test2
      - prefix: app3
        url: test3
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{prefix}}'
    spec:
      project: test
      source:
        repoURL: https://github.com/organisation/ABCDEF.git
        targetRevision: HEAD
        path: test/test
        helm:
          values: |
            image:
              repository: nginx
              pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              tag: "1.23.3"
      destination:
        server: '{{url}}'
        namespace: test
      syncPolicy:
        automated:
          prune: true
          selfHeal: true
        syncOptions:
          - CreateNamespace=true
```

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: This answer isn't correct for the original question as it shows using an `Application` resource and not the `ApplicationSet` the OP is using]

If it's a helm chart repo or it's a Umerala chart you should use it this way:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: pgbouncer-by-argocd-test
spec:
  destination:
    name: ''
    namespace: devops
    server: 'https://35.2.67.61'
  source:
    path: ''
    repoURL: 'https://development.mangos.com/mango/devops/pgbouncer.git'
    targetRevision: 1.0.1
    chart: master
  project: default
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: false
      selfHeal: false
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: OP shows that they're having an issue with using `ApplicationSet` and mention it works using `Application` instead; this answer only shows using `Application` and thus is incorrect/not applicable to OP's question.